# MacBook Pro 2018 in 24/7 nightmode - cursor on external monitor not in nightmode

Tags: display

Just got a MacBook Pro 2018. Upgraded from the 2017 MacBook Pro

I use my MacBook Pros in nightmode 24/7 since the bluelight hurts my eyes. I enabled nightmode on my new macbook pro and hooked it up to an external monitor but the cursor is unaffected by the nightmode changes.

I checked my 2017 and 2012 macbook pro and both change the cursor as well on the external monitor, just not the new macbook pro...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One quick thing you could try is resetting the NVRAM.

To reset the NVRAM on your model MacBook Pro follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your MBP reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you *may* need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).